# SQL FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT naming difference

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the difference between the following codes?

1.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

2.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

what is the use of adding name to our foreign key `constraint(FK_PersonOrder)` in the second code?

Comment: CONSTRAINT and foreign key name are optional. A foreign key is a constraint and if you don't provide a foreign key name mysql will create one (with a not very user friendly name)

Answer (score 1):

`ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder` is giving custom name to foriegn key else it will auto generate dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Both these statements are functionally the same. Giving a name to a foreign key (or any other constraint for that matter), makes working with it a tad easier - when a DML statement fails because it violates it it's easier to understand, it's easier to drop it if you choose to do so, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason we name anything; to describe it sufficiently that we understand what it is, or does

Sometimes database engines don't explicitly state any details about the other end of the relationship and in those cases it's a lot nicer to be inserting into your address table and see "constraint 'fk_person-addressid_address-id' violated" than "constraint 'fk_12ef3a2dc' violated" and be left thinking "hmmm, 12ef3a2dc/ was that the addresses table one? Or the job role one? Or the company one.. I'll just go and look in the dB to find out.."